# Bash Bell is a dog

Tags: bash, sound

So...weird question.

I know you can disable the bell sound in ubuntu bash through preferences.
I had it disabled as long as i can remember.
Now today I constantly thought some neighbors dog was barking... until i realized IT IS BASH THAT MAKES A BARK SOUND. The sound occurs where normally there would be the bell.
I am unable to disable that sound, wondering where the hell it came from in the first place.

I have tried turning it off by enabling and disabling the bell sound again. Bell sound is not played when enabled, instead the dog sound persists.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you set the `beep` command to an alias? (Enter `alias` to find out.)

Answer (score 0):

From the help on Terminal

**Set audible bell**

Terminal can sound an audible bell to indicate events in Terminal windows and tabs.
To be notified of these events:

- Press the menu button in the top-right corner of the window and select Preferences.
- In the sidebar, select your current profile in the Profiles section.
- Select Text.
- Select Terminal bell  ( **uncheck this** )

**Another solution if you want a different sound than bark**
Via Settings, Select the Sound category on the left.  To the right and at the bottom of the screen, the choices for *Alert Sound* are  in Ubuntu 20.04 at least

- Default
- Bark
- Drip
- Glass
- Sonar

Choose the Alert Sound that suits you best.